# RSpec: How can I not use `allow_any_instance_of` for objects that get instantiated in the functions I call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I have a class `A` with a method `M` for which I want to write a test `T`. The problem is that method `M` creates a new object `O`. I want to mock a method `F` of that new object `O`.

```rb
class A

  def M(p1, p2)
    @o = O.new(p1, p2)
  end

end

class O

  def F(q)
    ...
  end

end
```

I can very easily do so with the `allow_any_instance_of` feature of RSpec, but I really don't see a way of doing so with just `allow` or `expect`. I understand that I can mock a method of an existing instance and of a class but from my tests I couldn't make it work against methods of objects that get created in a method I'm testing.

```rb
T :process do
  it "works" do
    # This works
    allow_any_instance_of(O).to receive(:F).and_return(123)
    ...
  end

  it "does not works" do
    # This fails
    allow(O).to receive(:F).and_return(123)
    ...
  end
end
```

**How do I know that it fails?**

I changed my `F` method with a `puts()` and I can see that output on the screen when I use the `allow(O)`. It does not appear at all when I use the `allow_any_instance_of()`. So I know that it's working as expected only in the latter.

```
  def F(q)
    puts("If I see this, then F() was not mocked properly.")
    ...
  end
```

I would think that `allow(O)...` should connect to the class so whenever a new instance is created the mocked functions follow, but apparently not.

Do you have RSpec tests handling such mocking cases in a different way that would not involve the use of the `allow_any_instance_of()` function?

The reason I ask is because it is [marked as obsolete](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/old-syntax/any-instance) (`@allow-old-syntax`) since RSpec 3.3 so it sounds like we should not be using this feature anymore, especially once RSpec 4.x comes out, it probably will be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this

```
allow(O).to receive(:F).and_return(123)
```

Doesn't work is that `:F` is not a method of `O`, so the `O` never receives this message (method invocation).

The best solution for you would be to refactor your code to use dependency injection. (Please note that your example is abstract to the extreme, if you provided a real life example - closer to the ground - some better refactoring might be possible)

```
class A
  attr_accessor :o_implementation

  def initialize(o_implementation)
    @o_implementation = o_implementation
  end

  def M(p1, p2)
    @o = o_implementation.new(p1, p2)
  end

end

RSpec.describe A do
  subject { described_class.new(klass) }
  let(:klass) { O }
  let(:a_double) { instance_double(klass) }


  it do 
     allow(klass).to receive(:new).and_return(a_mock)
     allow(a_double).to receive(:F).and_return(123)
  end
end
```

With the Dependency injection you move outside the decision which class to instantiate. This decouples your code (A stops being coupled to O, now it depends only on the O interface that it's using), and makes it easier* to test.

(*) One could argue that `allow_any_instance` is easier (less involved, less typing), but it has [some issues](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance), and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Excellent. That may be a bit more involved than what we want to do right now, but it is a good idea and yes, the idea is to remove all `allow_any_instance`. (As a side note, in C++, we'd call that accessor either a callback or a factory.)

Answer (score 1):

(as a small aside: I can understand the probable need for very thorough anonymization of your code, but you could still follow ruby style guide: methods start with lower-case, only classes start with upper-case)

So first off: `allow(O)` works, but will only capture class methods. If you need to capture instance methods, you need to call `allow` for a specific instance.

Since your example is pretty sparse, I see no reason why we could not split up the creation of the object from the test? If that is possible, a very simple approach would be to write something like:

```
describe :process do 
  before do 
    @o = A.o_maker(p1,p2) 
    allow(@o).to receive(:some_function) { 123 } 
  end 
  it "works" do 
    # do something with `@o` that should call the function
  end
end
```

I personally prefer this approach over creating the mock class, as suggested before.
This is probably well known, but for clarity: the problem with a mock class imho is that you are no longer testing class `A` but the mock. This could in some cases be useful, but from the original question it is unclear if it applies in this case and if this is not needlessly complicated. And secondly: if your code *is* this complicated (e.g. some method that creates a new object and then calls `F`), I would rather 1) refactor my code to make it test-able, and/or 2) test side effects (e.g. `F` adds an audit-log-line, sets a state, ...). I do not need to "test" my implementation (is the correct method called), but is it performed (and of course, as always, there are exceptions e.g. when calling external services or something --but again all that is impossible to deduce from the original question).

Comment: I'm new to Ruby so the whole thing is a tag bit complicated to me. In our case, `F` is checking the database, which in the test we want to avoid. Also we want to verify that if `F` returns a certain value then `A` reacts appropriately. So it's certainly a case of _an external service_ (a database). That being said, it is not unlikely that the current implementation could be tweaked to make it more testable.